# Помогите разобрать алгоритм обхода графа построчно

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры

Вопросы и своё понимание алгоритмы я оставлю в комментариях к строкам.
Код взят с авторитетного алгоритмического сайта.
`

```
vector < vector<int> > g; // граф, почему вектор, а не массив ?
int n; // число вершин
int s; // стартовая вершина (вершины везде нумеруются с нуля)

// чтение графа
queue<int> q; // очередь для помещения туда узлов
q.push (s); // вставляю стартовую вершину в очередь
vector<bool> used (n); // булевый вектор для узлов, по которым прошёл ?
vector<int> d (n), p (n); // для чего еще два вектора ?
used[s] = true; // помещаю в вектор элемент с пометкой посещенная
p[s] = -1; // ??? для чего это ???
while (!q.empty()) { // выполнять цикл пока очередь не пуста
    int v = q.front(); // присвоить первый элем. очереди
    q.pop(); // удалить первый элемент из очереди
    for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) { // цикл выполняется пока итератор меньше чем граф
        int to = g[v][i]; // что мы здесь извлекаем из графа ? там же нет значения
        if (!used[to]) { // если to еще непосещенная, то ...
            used[to] = true; // ... отметить посещенной ...
            q.push (to); // ... вставить её в стек
            d[to] = d[v] + 1; // ???
            p[to] = v; // ???
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: В дополнение к ответу @MBo. `почему вектор, а не массив`, а вектор это не массив? `что мы здесь извлекаем из графа ? там же нет значения` вы видимо немного неправильно поняли как хранится граф. `g[v]` это список смежных вершин. Например, если g[3] равно {0, 4, 10}, значит третья вершина смежна с вершинам 0, 4 и 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это обход в ширину ([BFS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)). Понятие "по строкам" к графам не подходит.

Вектор используется, потому что удобно ;) (Списки смежности имеют разную длину)

`p[]` - предшественники (predecessor) - в `p[i]` записано, из какой вершины пришли в i-ю при данном обходе

`d[]` - расстояние (distance) от стартовой вершины

`for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) { // цикл выполняется пока итератор меньше чем граф`
здесь обходятся вершины, смежные с данной

`int to = g[v][i]; // что мы здесь извлекаем из графа ? там же нет значения`
индекс i-й вершины из списка смежности v-й вершины

Comment: для чего `p[s] = -1;` ?

Comment: Это означает, что у начальной вершины нет предшественника